# Accessing parent/grandparent/etc property from child (not inheritance)

Tags: javascript, oop, parent-child

Just wondering what the best practice is for the following situation, I've done a search but only seem to get results referencing parent/child inheritance which this is not, and I can't think of another way to word it!

Let's say I have the following simplified example objects:

- Map object (see edit below)
- Quote object, which contains:

  - Date object,
  - Route object, which contains:

    - Array of waypoints, each contains:

      - Site object, which contains the following properties:

        - Latitude
        - Longitude

Now if I wanted to calculate the sunrise/sunset times at a specific site I would need the date, latitude and longitude. As it stands at the moment my site object has the following (pseudocode) function:

```
var Site = function() {
    var lat;
    var lng;

    var calculateSunriseSunset = function(date) {
        // do calculation with lat, lng and date
        return result;
    }
}
```

and for example I might call the function like so:

```
site.calculateSunriseSunset(quote.get('date')); // site here is a reference to a specific site object
```

where 'quote' is a global reference to the parent Quote object. To me this is ugly and seems bad practice (circular reference? coupled?).

However, the only two other options I can think of are:

- move the calculateSunriseSunset to the Quote object and pass it the site and the date as parameters (but this seems like bad practice because the sunrise and sunset is related to the specific site, and there are *a lot* of examples of this spread over many different objects - I'm worried by doing this the Quote object will just become a messy catch-all)
- pass the date to the route object as a parameter when it's constructed, which in turn loops through each waypoint updating each site with the set date. This seems messy, especially when the date gets changed and the whole process has to be done again.

Is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing?

Thanks

**EDIT**

1) To clarify what I meant by 'global reference' I just meant that I had used the following code:

```
var quote = new Quote();
```

where quote was defined in the global namespace, and callable from anywhere.

---

2) The 'calculateSunriseSunset' function is being called from another object, a 'Map' object which deals with everything to do with the map that is displayed to the user. It looks a little like this (much simplified for clarity):

```
var Map = function() {
    var sites; // list of sites loaded from the server
    var leafletMap; // reference to the [Leaflet][1] map object used to do the 'heavy lifting'
    var root = this;

    showSites = function() {
        var siteLayer = L.geoJson(sites, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.on('click', function (e) {
                    root.openPopup(e.target.feature);
                });
             },
        }).addTo(leafletMap);
    }

    this.openPopup = function(site) {
        var popup = L.popup().setContent(site.calculateSunriseSunset(quote.get('date'))).openOn(leafletMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Various approaches would depend on how you construct and modify this whole object in the first place. Not really enough known in that regard. There are also numerous ways to have getters and setters on an object that won't affect original object structure

Comment: What do you mean by "global reference"? Who will be calling `calculateSunriseSunset`? Please show more of your code.

Comment: Edited as requested to answer your questions, thanks Bergi.

Comment: Charliefl, can you explain a bit more what you mean by 'There are also numerous ways to have getters and setters on an object that won't affect original object structure'? I'm a little confused as to how that would help? Thanks!